# WhereBetween not found on eloquent hasmany

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Using Laravel 5. I have a model Property, that has many Weeks available to it. This is the Property Model.

```
<?php namespace App\Models;


use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * @property mixed week
 */
class Property extends Model
{


    public function week()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Week', 'PropertyID', 'PropertyID');
    }

}
```

I am trying to use WhereBetween on a hasMany relation of an object using the WhereBetween method. This is the error I get though.

Method 'WhereBetween' not found in class 'illumainate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany.

```
list($from, $to) = $params->get('range');


$week = $property->week()
   ->whereBetween('WeekDate', array($from, $to))
   ->get();
```

The same error occurs if I try WhereRaw instead of WhereBetween. hasMany class doesn't have WhereRaw or WhereBetween. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Mind the casing. There is a difference between **w**hereBetween and **W**hereBetween.

Comment: Thanks, not a casing issue.

Comment: What's the exact Laravel version you are using?

Comment: "require": {
  "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "~1.0",
  "dingo/api": "0.9.*@dev",
      "lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel": "~4.0",
      "mitulgolakiya/laravel-api-generator": "1.3.*",
  "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.0"

Comment: WhereBetween is cleaner, but I can use the following to get around this problem:-                                                                                        $week = $property->week()
            ->where('WeekDate', '>', $from)
            ->where('WeekDate', '<', $to)
            ->get();

Comment: You keep writing **W**hereBetween in your comments. Are you sure you're not writing that in your code as well?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in Laravel 5.2 with the following code:

```
$events = Events::whereBetween('start', array($start, $end))
                ->whereBetween('end', array($start, $end))
                ->get();
```

This throws an error like:

> Call to undefined method App\Events::whereBetween()

Somehow in Laravel 5.0+ I could not use whereBeetween directly on the model. But in the API documentation whereBetween is still listed as function of the DB class ([see here](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereBetween)). By replacing the model with the DB class we can fix it:

```
use DB;
...
$events = DB::table('events')
          ->whereBetween('start', array($start, $end))
          ->whereBetween('end', array($start, $end))
          ->get();
```